# how to precent http interceptors if offline

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm building an app with ionic and I'm showing a loading indicator on every request that loads. When the request finishes, the loading indicator is removed. This works great when a network connection is present.

When offline, the request starts and the loading indicator is show. Problem is that the loading indicator never disappears because the request never finishes. How can I best handle this? I'm thinking about a timeout or something. The best way would be not to start the request at all when a user is offline.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope) {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        config.timeout = 5000;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')
        return config
      },
      response: function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
        return response
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: You should also try to handle requestError and responseError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below

```
  responseError: function(response) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
    return response
  }


  requestError: function(response) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
    return response
  }
```

Comment: Fantastic, didn't know about those events!